# Membership data

Tags: civireport

Recently tried to pull a membership report & the reports keep turning up zero info.
Looking at the contacts, and specifically looking up members, it appears that their member box is suddenly unchecked?!
We recently refreshed our wordpress website & when the new site went live there was a conflict between CiviCRM and another plugin. Once that plugin was deactivated CiviCRM appeared to work fine. But now this has happened.
All other data appears to be there. All other reports seem to be generating with no problem, but this membership issue.
Is there something that has suddenly been "unchecked"?
Is there an easy solution?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: `their member box` - can you either describe what screen that's on or edit your question to include a screenshot? It's not terminology usually used in civi.